# Plt fig saving as blank image (with the right size?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I have tried using the answers I have seen throughout the existing questions and still cant figure out why my figure is saving as a blank.

It shows up in the notebook but the file that is saved is blank. Lmk what you think

```
fig_list = np.array([sel_geophy, sel_geochem, sel_geol, sel_struct])
fig_list_text= np.array(['sel_geophy', 'sel_geochem', 'sel_geol', 'sel_struct'])

k=1

#for f in range (0,fig_list.shape[0]):
for f in range (0,2):    
    plt.figure(figsize=[15,5])
    print(df[fig_list[f]])
    print('target column',targetcolumn)
    fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df[fig_list[f]], color=targetcolumn,color_continuous_scale= 'Bluered', color_continuous_midpoint=0.5)
    fig.update_layout(autosize=False,width=3000,height=300)
    outpath = 'C:/Users/philipped/Google Drive/JupyterNotebooks/graphoutput/' +'parrallel_coord/' + str(fig_list_text[f]) +'_' + str(targetlist[k]) +'.jpeg'
    print(outpath)
    plt.savefig(outpath)
    fig.show()
```

[image: looks good here...]

Answer (score 0):

Im using the matplotlib export function instead of the plotly export function...

I have to use

```
fig.write_image(outpath2)
```

instead.